# Django WSGI not working with apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm trying to configure the WSGI in Apache to work with Django but it's not working, when I go to domain.com it gives me an error 500.

But If I start Django using:

```
python manage.py runserver domain.com:8000
```

When I go to domain.com:8000 works perfectly so I think It's something about apache and WSGI.

Here you have my WSGI script:

```
import os
import sys  
sys.path.append('/var/www/domain/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'domain.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

My VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/domain/domain.wsgi

    #Alias /static/ /var/www/domain/static/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04**. I tried looking at logs but I have no idea what's wrong.

Logs:

```
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.549670 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477] mod_wsgi (pid=17141): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/domain/domain.wsgi'.
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.549722 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.549747 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.549880 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.549899 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550029 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550048 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 236, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550075 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550091 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 91, in technical_500_response
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550492 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550513 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 350, in get_traceback_html
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550539 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return t.render(c)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550554 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 148, in render
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.550984 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return self._render(context)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551006 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 142, in _render
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551034 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551048 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551071 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551084 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 80, in render_node
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551174 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return node.render(context)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551192 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 90, in render
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551217 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551231 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 624, in resolve
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551268 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551284 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 769, in date
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551595 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return format(value, arg)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551615 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 343, in format
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551759 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return df.format(format_string)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551778 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551817 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551834 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 268, in r
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551857 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551871 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551892 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.551907 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 85, in force_text
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552021 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     s = six.text_type(s)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552039 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 144, in __text_cast
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552276 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552297 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 83, in ugettext
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552412 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return _trans.ugettext(message)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552431 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 325, in ugettext
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552686 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552706 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 306, in do_translate
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552731 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552746 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 209, in translation
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552768 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552782 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 189, in _fetch
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552804 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477]     "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
[Thu Sep 25 10:15:09.552830 2014] [:error] [pid 17141] [client 88.12.185.72:65477] AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover that the version of Django in my production server is 1.7.0 and in Development server is 1.6.4. After downgrade Django works fine.

```
sudo pip install django==1.6.4
```